# In github actions, using Ubuntu 20.04, how to install a specific version of gawk?

Tags: awk, github-actions, ubuntu-20.04, apt

By default, the version of awk available in Ubuntu 20.04 with github actions is:

```
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
```

I would like to know how (if possible) to install GAWK 5.0.0. The following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install gawk=5.0.0
```

Give:

```
E: Version '5.0.0' for 'gawk' was not found
```

If possible, how would I achieve that ?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't ship GNU Awk version 5.0.0. You can install `gawk>=1:5.0.0` if you are on a version which supports this version (notice also the epoch part of the version number, `1:`). 20.04 ships 1:5.0.1 out of the box. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gawk The previous version before that was 1:4.2.1.

Comment: @tripleee Yup, I literaly just figured that out with `apt-cache policy gawk`.